# WSO2 GREG - Asset Models with more ESB

Tags: registry, wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

I'm following the procedure described at this documentation url:

> https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/ESB+Asset+Models

The configuration works fine trying it with >> WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and 1 WSO2 GREG 4.6.0.
What about the task configuration in the registry.xml, if I have two WSO2 ESB connected with the registry?
Thanks

Comment: You can refer [this article][1] 
If you had any issues better send it to wso2 mailing list dev@wso2.org


  [1]: http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/wso2-enterprise-service-bus-wso2-governance-registry-integration/

Comment: In my case i tried to replicate the code,

<task name="MediationTask" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.platform.extensions.mediation.MediationArtifactPopulatorTask">

          ....
Adding another MediationTask (mediationTask). In this way i d like to have 2 Esb synchronizing their artifacts with the governance registry.
But after rebooting the Greg it seems to be a conflict situation in wich just one artifact (from ESB1 or ESB2) is uploaded into the registry.

Thanks